# textbox does not allow for backspace to be pressed?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, key

I have made a textbox, which restricts character use to numbers and periods only. Nice, but now I can't enter backspace to amend any data typed in my textbox. How can I fix this?

```
    Private Sub TextBox10_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox10.KeyPress

    Dim allowedChars As String = "1234567890."

    If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
        ' Invalid Character
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test for backspace by using

```
If e.KeyChar = ChrW(8) Then
    MessageBox.Show("backspace!")
End If
```

So your whole code would become:

```
Private Sub TextBox10_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox10.KeyPress

    Dim allowedChars As String = "1234567890."

    If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 andalso
            Not e.KeyChar = ChrW(8) Then
        ' Invalid Character
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Similar question: [How can I accept the backspace key in the keypress event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191698/how-can-i-accept-the-backspace-key-in-the-keypress-event)